# Is it possible to mount EFS on Databricks (AWS)

Tags: databricks, amazon-efs, aws-databricks

I have run the following code from a databricks notebook:

```py
dbutils.fs.mount('<ip_address>', '/mnt/efs')
```

And I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported scheme: null. Allowed schemes are: gs,s3a,s3n,wasbs,adl,abfss.
```

I have have pinged my EFS IP address from my Databricks notebook and I do not get errors on that side.

Moreover I have tried following this [blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/05/17/nfs-mounting-in-databricks-product.html), but by running this command:

```
%sh
mkdir -m 777 /mnt/efs
mount -t nfs4 -o nosuid,nodev <ip_address>:/ /mnt/efs
```

I get this error:

```
mount: /mnt/efs: cannot mount <ip_address>:/ read-only.
```

For your information, I am using Databricks on AWS.

Comment: Are you using  Single Tenant Workspace or E2 workspace?

Comment: Note: The solution in this blog is only known to work on AWS single-tenant deployments and may not work on Azure Databricks.